# historical comments in bad taste

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematics-social-history

On page 44 of [1] Flanders writes "A treatment from this point of view of exterior calculus
which is not quite completely satisfactory and which unfortunately is embellished
with historical comments often in bad taste is found in Blaschke." His reference is Baschke's book [2] as listed on page 197.

What comments did Flanders think were in bad taste in [2] and what/why did he consider Blaschke's presentation an unsatisfactory treatment when compared to his?

[1] Flanders: Differential Forms with Applications to the Physical Sciences, Dover Pubs. 1989,

[2] Blaschke: Einfuhrung in die Differentialgeometrie, Berlin 1950.

Comment: Book [2] has only 146 pages. https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0041.28804

Comment: @Alexandre_Eremenko a dangling participle... page 197 of the Flanders book refers to that of Blaschke as "[3]"